# Does we need to register the sources in Data factory

Tags: azure-purview

I have question on Azure Purview. If you add your Data Factory in Azure Purview, and trigger the Data Factory, will Azure Purview will show the Data factory and Sources and Sink details in Lineage. Will that be searchable in Data catalog, or do we need to register those source and sink database in Purview and run scan.
Asking this because my application integrates with Azure through REST APIs and REST API is not a source in Azure purview, but it is in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

The lineage data will automatically be captured during the activities execution.

After you run the pipeline, in the pipeline monitoring view, you can check the lineage reporting status by clicking the following Lineage status button. The same information is also available in the activity output JSON -> reportLineageToPurvew section.

On Microsoft Purview UI, you can browse assets and choose type "Azure Data Factory". You can also search the Data Catalog using keywords.

The generated lineage data is based on the type of source and sink used in the Data Factory activities. Although Data Factory supports over 80 source and sinks, Microsoft Purview supports only a subset, as listed in [Supported Azure Data Factory activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-link-azure-data-factory#supported-azure-data-factory-activities).

For more detailed info about the lineage limitaitons w.r.t Azure Data Factory runs, please refer to below docs:

1. [ADF Supported lineage patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-link-azure-data-factory#supported-lineage-patterns)
2. [Run pipeline and push lineage data to Microsoft Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-push-lineage-to-purview#run-pipeline-and-push-lineage-data-to-microsoft-purview)